# Multiple elastislide viewers on single page

Tags: jquery, image-gallery, image-viewer, elastislide

I need to have multiple elastislide viewers on my webpage, but I can't for the life of me get them to work... I tried using the example of a solved similar question on here, but it still wont work.

If anyone could show me some code, or a real working example that I could reverse engineer that would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check this post: [Need for multiple elastislide image viewers on one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429373/need-for-multiple-elastislide-image-viewers-on-one-page)

Personally the best solution for me is the one with the "each" function

```
jQuery('.carousel').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).elastislide( {
        minItems : 2
    });
});
```

It would be nice to give us some example code so we can see where the problem exactly is